# Prestashop FrontController override not working

Tags: php, prestashop-1.6, overriding

I override frontController in override\classes\controller\FrontController.php. I added only simple code

```
    class FrontController extends FrontControllerCore
    {    
    init()
{
        [...]
        $logo_image_url = 'themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/img/shop/'.Tools::getValue('controller').'.png';
        if (!file_exists($logo_image_url)) $logo_image_url = 'themes/'._THEME_NAME_.'/img/shop/main.png';
        [...]
        $this->context->smarty->assign(array(
        // Usefull for layout.tpl
        [...]
        'logo_shop_image' => $logo_image_url,
        ));
    [...]
    }
    }
```

And in header.tpl i added img with **src="{$logo_shop_image}"**. I delete **class_index.php** and after page refresh it is working (**class_index.php** was regenerated) on my localhost.

Overridedcode not working on my server. **$logo_shop_image** is always empty. I regenerating **class_index.php** too, it looks like presta stil uses **original** **FrontController** because when i override original code then it works. How to force using override file in override catalog?

I interested in class_index.php file and i saw something strange.

```
  'FrontController' => 
  array (
    'path' => 'override/classes/controller/FrontController.php',
    'type' => 'class',
    'override' => false,
  ),
```

Why 'override' => false? This is file from working localhost. Is it important?

Answer (score -2):

It's something with `_PS_HOST_MODE_` config attribute.

Comment: Please explain in detail what you mean John Doe